# Несколько ссылок на модальное окно

Tags: javascript

На странице есть несколько одинаковых ссылок на одно и то же модальное окно, но событие вешается только на первую ссылку по счёту, что прописать, чтобы можно было взаимодействовать со всеми ссылками? Знаю, что можно сделать через массив, но я не могу сам допетрить, потому что я совсем новичок.

```js
var link = document.querySelector('.modal__link');
var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
var close = modal.querySelector('.modal-sent__button');

// Открытие окна
link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    modal.classList.add('modal--open');
});

// закрытие окна
close.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    modal.classList.remove('modal--open');
});

window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.classList.remove('modal--open');
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.modal--open {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<a class="modal__link" href="#modal__wrapper">уточняйте у менеджера</a>

<div class="modal">
    <div>
        <button class="modal-sent__button" type="button">
    <svg class="modal-sent__icon" width="40" height="40">
                <use href="img/sprite.svg#close"></use>
            </svg>
    </button>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input placeholder="Ваше имя*" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input placeholder="Контактный телефон*">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input placeholder="Email*">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <textarea placeholder="Комментарий"></textarea>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//var link = document.querySelector('.modal__link');
var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
var close = modal.querySelector('.modal-sent__button');

// Открытие окна
document.querySelectorAll('.modal__link').forEach(
  link => link.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    modal.classList.add('modal--open');
  })
);
```